# Mocha async callback and Sequelize promise are not synchronize?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, sequelize.js, es6-promise

I'm writing test cases with [mocha](http://mochajs.org) and its hook `beforeEach` which deletes and re-creates all tables using `sequelize.drop` and `sequelize.sync`.

#### lib/testutils.js

```
exports.deleteAll = function () {
    return sequelize.drop({logging: false, cascade: true}).then(function() {
        return sequelize.sync({logging: false});
    });
};
```

#### test/controllers/controllers.js

**(A)** This did work:

```
var testutils = require("../../lib/testutils");

describe("CRUD Controller", function() {
    beforeEach(function(done) {
        testutils.deleteAll().then(function(){
            done();
        }).catch(function(err) {
            return done(err);
        });
    });

    describe("#read()", function(){
        it("should....", function(done) {
        });
    });
}
```

**(B)** This did not work:

```
var testutils = require("../../lib/testutils");

describe("CRUD Controller", function() {
    beforeEach(function(done) {
        testutils.deleteAll().then(done).catch(function(err) {
            return done(err);
        });
    });

    describe("#read()", function(){
        it("should....", function(done) {
        });
    });
}
```

I don't understand why `testutils.deleteAll().then(done)` did not work and the first test case `it("should....", function(done)` did not wait for the `beforeEach` hook finished. I was getting `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`. However, `testutils.deleteAll().then(function(){ done(); })` did work.

My question is why **(B)** is not working while **(A)** is working? Any idea? Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mocha supports promises in beforeEach so just write below code:

```
beforeEach(function(){
  return testutils.deleteAll();
});
```

Comment: I got `......... "before each" hook: Error: timeout of 15000ms exceeded`. Calling `done()` is a must.

Comment: Try setting bigger timeout as `done()` might not work with promises.

Comment: Remember to remove the `done` parameter from your functions if you are returning a promise.

Comment: @MickHansen Completely removing `done` did solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: This answer solved the problem, but did not answer the question directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your `deleteAll()` function returns `sequelize.sync()` which returns a promise passing it `this`. I think the context will be the last model created, so when you pass a function to the returned promise, the function will be passed the last table created. So in case (A) you specified the `function()`
and called `done()` manually without passing any args to `done()`. But in case (B) when you pass done to the `promise.then()`, the last model created will be passed to done.

To get what I mean consider the following:

```
  User.create({name: 'aName'}).then(function(user){console.log(user)});
```

is equivalent to

```
  User.create({name: 'aName'}).then(console.log);
```

The user will be automatically passed to `console.log()`.

So `done` was being passed the last model created which I think might cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `done` directly it receive object returned from `deleteAll`, and mocha treat it as an error, so it try apply `JSON.stringify` to this object and show it as an error, but somehow `JSON.stringify` can't do it, so it throw exception which you can see.
You can clearly see it in `Mocha::Runnable#run`